# A proof involving derivatives of Dirac delta functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differentiation, density-operator, dirac-delta-distributions

Let us define

$$\tag{1}
    Q=i\nabla_\mathbf{k}\delta(\mathbf{k-k'})\left[\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k'})-\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k})\right],
$$

where $\delta(\mathbf{k})$ is a Dirac delta, and $\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k})$ is a reduced density matrix. I wish to show that
$$\tag{2}
Q =i\delta(\mathbf{k-k'})\nabla_\mathbf{k}\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k}).
$$
My strategy relies on the idea that
$$\tag{3}
Q=\nabla_\mathbf{k}\int d\mathbf{k}\,Q.
$$
Let us integrate and differentiate $Q$ with respect to $\mathbf{k},$
$$
    Q = \nabla_\mathbf{k}\int d\mathbf{k} \,Q \nonumber \\
      = \nabla_\mathbf{k}\int d\mathbf{k} \left(i\nabla_\mathbf{k}\delta(\mathbf{k-k'})\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k'})-i\nabla_\mathbf{k}\delta(\mathbf{k-k'})\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k}) \right), \nonumber \\
      = i\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k'})\nabla_\mathbf{k}\int d\mathbf{k}\,\nabla_\mathbf{k}\delta(\mathbf{k'-k})
     -i\nabla_\mathbf{k}\int d\mathbf{k}\,\nabla_\mathbf{k}\delta(\mathbf{k-k'})\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k}).
\tag{4}
$$
The first term vanishes, since the derivative of a delta function is odd. To evaluate the second term, we use the identity
$$\tag{5}
    \int\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x-x')f(x)dx=-\int\delta(x-x')\frac{d}{dx}f(x)dx,
$$
to obtain
$$\tag{6}
    Q = i\nabla_\mathbf{k}\int d\mathbf{k}\,\delta(\mathbf{k-k'})\nabla_\mathbf{k}\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k}).
$$
Comparison with the first line of Eq. (4) yields
$$\tag{7}
    Q = i\delta(\mathbf{k-k'})\nabla_\mathbf{k}\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k}).
$$
What if we had chosen to integrate and differentiate $Q$ with respect to $\mathbf{k'}$ instead? We will need the identities
$$\tag{8}
    \frac{d}{dx}\delta(x-x')=-\frac{d}{dx'}\delta(x-x'), \qquad \delta(x-x')=\delta(x'-x).
$$
Applying Eq. (8) to Eq. (1),
$$\tag{9}
    Q = i\nabla_\mathbf{k}\delta(\mathbf{k-k'})\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k'})-i\nabla_\mathbf{k}\delta(\mathbf{k-k'})\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k}) \\
       = -i\nabla_\mathbf{k'}\delta(\mathbf{k-k'})\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k'})-i\nabla_\mathbf{k}\delta(\mathbf{k-k'})\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k}) \\
        = -i\nabla_\mathbf{k'}\delta(\mathbf{k'-k})\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k'})-i\nabla_\mathbf{k}\delta(\mathbf{k-k'})\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k}).
$$
Integrating and differentiating $Q$ with respect to $\mathbf{k'}$ this time,
$$
    Q = \nabla_\mathbf{k'}\int d\mathbf{k'} Q \nonumber \\
     = \nabla_\mathbf{k'}\int d\mathbf{k'} \left(-i\nabla_\mathbf{k'}\delta(\mathbf{k'-k})\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k'})-i\nabla_\mathbf{k}\delta(\mathbf{k-k'})\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k}) \right) \nonumber \\
     = \nabla_\mathbf{k'}\int d\mathbf{k'} i\delta(\mathbf{k'-k})\nabla_\mathbf{k'}\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k'}) -i\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k})\nabla_\mathbf{k}\nabla_\mathbf{k'}\int d\mathbf{k'}\delta(\mathbf{k-k'}),
\tag{10}
$$
where to obtain the first term in the last line we have used Eq. (5), and where the second term in vanishes because the integral just gives $1.$ Equating the integrands of the first and last lines of Eq. (10), we obtain
$$\tag{11}
    Q=i\delta(\mathbf{k-k'})\nabla_\mathbf{k'}\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k'}),
$$
which, if $\mathbf{k}=\mathbf{k'},$ agrees with the desired result. That is, if $\mathbf{k}=\mathbf{k'},$ Eqs. (2), (7), and (11) unambiguously give
$$\tag{12}
    Q=i\nabla_\mathbf{k}\rho_{nm}(\mathbf{k}).
$$
However, if $\mathbf{k}=\mathbf{k'},$ then Eq. (1) gives $0$ immediately...

Even if my proof is flawed, I believe the result Eq. (2) is correct (see [Aversa & Sipe 1995](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.52.14636)). Can anyone comment on the use of Eq. (3), or provide a simple alternative proof?

Answer (score 2):

I think you  are forgetting the distributional identity
$$
f(x) \delta'(x) = f(0)\delta'(x)- f'(x)\delta(x), 
$$
which is easily proved with the use of a suitable test function.

Comment: The idea being that the desired result follows immediately if $\rho_{cc}(0)=0$?

Comment: Yes. I think so.  Just introduce a test function  to make it rigourous.

Comment: Cheers, I'll give it a go :)